# How to run terminal commands when terminal itself isn't responding?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

Mac paused all my running apps (including Terminal) when the OS was low on memory. Now due to a Mac bug, the paused apps wouldn't continue even while I had clicked resume. I'd like to send SIGCONT (`kill -cont`) to the Terminal app.

Is there an alternative Terminal?

Comment: did you try force quit from Apple menu?

Comment: @jmh, I used Terminal to run scripts and apps... quitting it will cause data loss to itself and its child processes which is why I'm trying to send SIGCONT to it to tell it to resume. | Btw, in Windows, each cmd is standalone and independent, thus there would never be a situation where cmd commands cannot be run. Why would Mac bind all windows into one process and shldnt there be a way to open an independent window?

Comment: And you tried opening a new terminal window?  Do you have iTerm? Its another terminal program. Maybe use that to open new terminal window?

Comment: @jmh,  You mean rightclick new window ([not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfzAU.png)) or? Will give iTerm a try next time as in the meanwhile I found a fix (c below)

Answer (score 3):

Ok found a fix. I copypaste `Terminal.app`, giving me two terminal apps. While the first is screwed, the second one works fine aside from some quirks (eg app2 tries to open opened app1∙windows  instead of being fully independent like in Windows)

Comment: Does this happen often to you?

Answer (score 2):

No. When you’ve gotten a system in extreme and memory is fully committed, your only home is to ssh in remotely or get lucky with an app launch.

You might need to just power off the machine and pick up the pieces of lost and unsaved data as needed.

Unless you have the shell already open, chances of spawning a new one are slim.

Force quitting any non needed apps might also get you a narrow window to resume control.